# Trouble reading ajax post response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am working on a website and I am trying to connect JavaScript and php using ajax. I have a problem with reading ajax response.

I have one php script which has the following code:

```
<?php
echo "1";
```

And a function written in JavaScript ecma 6, which has the following code:

```
loginUser(username, password) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            var request = require('ajax-request');
            request.post(
                {
                    url: 'http://swiftservice.psoftwarestudio.com/Admin.php',
                    data: {
                        username: username,
                        password: password
                    },
                    headers: {}
                }
                , (data) => {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

When I debug, the data is always null. I am very new at web programming especially whit ajax. 
I hope someone can point me to the error, thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into browser's developer tools?

Comment: @Anton There is no error, when i put data into watch, and stop on the line when I call resolve, it says data is null, and that is all. If that is the question

Comment: Please send headers, as it is a good practice, like: headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json','Content-Type': 'application/json',}. And try to return json from server side. Try to use Source tab in chrome to debug your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the documentation of the `ajax-request` module and noticed that the callback takes 3 arguments: `function(err, res, body) {`.

Perhaps the required data is in the third?

Comment: the reason i used only one parameter is the post here i saw

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the `data` you get back from your AJAX call into a JSON Object, as what you get is the String representation of it:

```
loginUser(username, password) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            var request = require('ajax-request');
            request.post(
                {
                    url: 'http://swiftservice.psoftwarestudio.com/Admin.php',
                    data: {
                        username: username,
                        password: password
                    },
                    headers: {}
                }
                , (data) => {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: if he gets null it's not the problem :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic just realized that it's Node Code... >.<

Comment: Username and password in data, am i missing " " there?

Comment: @PetarMijović no, you're not. In JS you can build JSON-Objects without quotes

Comment: @LucaKiebel I asked because, I altered php script, and $_POST is empty, I thought that was the reason, any suggestions?

Comment: can you `console.log` the username and password before you send it to your PHP script?

Comment: @LucaKiebel They are okay before creating request

Comment: @PetarMijović If you are on Localhost there might be some Problem with the request going through, or maybe it's the JSON that your PHP doesn't accept, anyhow, take a look at [Postman](http://getpostman.com) for API testing, you'll find what you need there.